# insertRowsAtIndexPaths inserts rows a

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to insert a row after the user has pressed return on the keyboard. 
The code inside the textFieldShouldReturn method looks like this:

```
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1)] - 1)
                                                inSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1)];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[lastIndexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

This works fine until 10 rows are shown, after which a row is inserted at the beginning and then one and the end of the tableView.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the value of lastIndexPath ... ?

Comment: The value of lastIndexPath is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you have not updated your data. And one o both methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

of `UITableViewDataSource` returns wrong data.

UITableView only displays data. You should store it yourself somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, it's just strange that it works first and then stops working properly.

Comment: The data returned by numberOfRowsInSection is correct.

Comment: @sixbeat, you can add additional code to your question or open another one. Now it is not enough information to say what else could be wrong.